# Zend Framework Own Session Manager class

Tags: php, zend-framework

I created my own Session Manager class I only overrode one method which is the destroy($id) method. I wrote there this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $result = parent::destroy($id);
    $model = new Model_User();
    $model->logoutUser($id);
    return $result;
}
```

the logoutUser(); method deletes the logged in user from the logged_users table because everytime a user logs in i write their session id and userid in the logged_users table. But apparently the method is not being called cause everytime I check the table the user is not logged out. What could be the problem?

Comment: How are you telling the app to use your custom SessionManager class?

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet seems to be okay, so I'm guessing the problem occurs somewhere later, probably in `Model_User::logoutUser()` or when trying to `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` in your `logged_users`-table. Try `echo` and `die($variable)` in your code blocks, to see if they are executed and that variables are set as expected (e.g. check in your Model_User if logoutUser() is called and $id was actually passed). Even better, take your time and learn basic unit-testing. ;)

Side-note: There seems to be some duplication in your code, as your Model_User should not perform an action like logout(). Take a look at [Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html), if you want to have session states in a table. Having some kind of session handler AND the user_model maintain a `logged_users`-table seems unnecessary.